# Check if current category is child of another

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I'm quite new to WooCommerce and have a little problem.

I have three menus;
Sportmenu
Erhvervmenu
Interventionmenu

When i'm in the category Sport and it's child categories, it has to show Sportmenu. When I'm in the category Erhverv and it's child categories, it has to show Erhvervmenu.

I have no idea how to do this, and i've tried a variation of things.

Comment: I'm slightly confused with what you are wanting to achieve, is this a vertical collapsing menu? Could you link to an example or an image?

Comment: It's a vertical menu yes. The only thing i need, is to know how i check, if I'm currently in a category which is a child of either Sport, Erhverv or Intervention. I tried with get_categories and check if the $_POST['product_cat'] was in the array from get_categories, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Something this way maybe:

```
<? if ( have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
    $categ = $product->get_categories();
    $term = get_term_by ( 'name' , strip_tags($categ), 'product_cat' );
    if( $term->parent!=0 && ( $term->slug == YOUR_CAT_SLUG ) ){
        // DO SOMETHING
     } // end if term
    } // end while
}// end if have_posts
?>
```

Comment: When i do this, it says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in sidebar.php on line 18" - which is "if($term->parent!=0 && ( $term->slug == YOUR_CAT_SLUG){"
I added a ) after YOUR_CAT_SLUG) to prevent this, and it said "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in sidebar.php on line 48. Which is the last line and has nothing to do with what you just wrote. I guess it's because it needs a } or something?

Comment: Yes, i missed some { and ), updated, now it will work.